# mongodb return object and array separate

Tags: php, mongodb, return, phalcon

I use phalcon framework and mongo db. 
I show you 2 different ways. First return not right result, but second way return right result(he use default php extension).

Why i get different results? And how parse it?

Sample in phalcon(way 1):

```
    $documents = new AdminModel();
    $cursor = $documents->find(array(
        'login' => 'hello'
    ));

    echo "<pre>";
    foreach($cursor as $doc){
        foreach($doc as $prop){
            var_dump($prop);
        }
    }
    echo "</pre>";
```

How looks AdminModel(way 1):

```
    class AdminModel extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Collection{

        public function getSource()
        {
            return "accounts";
        }
    }
```

Result(way 1):

```
    object(MongoId)#70 (1) {
      ["$id"]=>
      string(24) "540822d55d34c4087a320064"
    }

    array(3) {
      ["login"]=>
      string(3) "one"
      ["password"]=>
      string(60) "$2y$10$RB2PvyRWxD7kdZcYpb8BGO6E/2ftbAEwnJ/28TBWUaDmX.iesPqY2"
      ["role"]=>
      string(4) "user"
    }
```

And when i try use default extension(way 2):

```
    $mongo = new \MongoClient();
    $db = $mongo->weather;
    $collection = $db->accounts;

    $cursor = $collection->find();

    echo "<pre>";
    foreach($cursor as $doc){
            var_dump($doc);echo "1<br/>";
    }
    echo "</pre>";
```

Result(way 2):

```
    array(2) {
      ["_id"]=>
      object(MongoId)#72 (1) {
        ["$id"]=>
        string(24) "540822d55d34c4087a320064"
      }
      ["user"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["login"]=>
        string(3) "one"
        ["password"]=>
        string(60) "$2y$10$RB2PvyRWxD7kdZcYpb8BGO6E/2ftbAEwnJ/28TBWUaDmX.iesPqY2"
        ["role"]=>
        string(4) "user"
      }
    }
```

UPDATE:

```
        foreach($cursor as $model){
            echo $model->user['login']."<br/>";
            echo $model->user['password']."<br/>";
            echo $model->user['role']."<br/>";
        }
```

two
$2y$10$RB2PvyRWxD7kdZcYpb8BGO6E/2ftbAEwnJ/28TBWUaDmX.iesPqY2
admin
three
$2y$10$RB2PvyRWxD7kdZcYpb8BGO6E/2ftbAEwnJ/28TBWUaDmX.iesPqY2
guest

Notice: Undefined property: Weather\Model\AdminModel::$user in /Users/rd/sites/app/controllers/Admin/IndexController.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined property: Weather\Model\AdminModel::$user in /Users/rd/sites/app/controllers/Admin/IndexController.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined property: Weather\Model\AdminModel::$user in /Users/rd/sites/app/controllers/Admin/IndexController.php on line 21

I told, what find return 1 object and 1 array. What we see, $model try access to:

```
    object(MongoId)#70 (1) {
      ["$id"]=>
      string(24) "540822d55d34c4087a320064"
    }
```

And then we get Notice.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean why??? You use two completely different things hence you get two completely different results. Mongo client returns your JSON documents as is. Phalcon uses Mongo client (maybe not the same one) to retrieve those documents and maps them to your models for a more convenient use. So, `AdminModel::find` internally calls `Collection::find` and then stores the result in own format, which you see when dumping the var.

See [ODM (Object-Document Mapper) documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/odm.html), it talks more about the implementation and how to use it.

**Edit:**

You don't really need to parse it, because the model supposed to do this for you. To access your data you can do the following.

```
$documents = new AdminModel();
$cursor = $documents->find(array(
    'login' => 'hello'
));

foreach($cursor as $model){
    var_dump($model->user);
    echo $model->user['login'];
    echo $model->user['password'];
    echo $model->user['role'];
}

$model = $documents->findFirst(array(
    'login' => 'hello'
));
var_dump($model->user);
echo $model->user['login'];
echo $model->user['password'];
echo $model->user['role'];
```

PS: you also have a nested loop in first example, otherwise (I assume) it would show an object with `id` and `user` properties.

Comment: You seriously? I read this documentation, there show how use without subdocument. I get 2 elements, first is object, second is array. And how i can parse it?

Comment: If i will parse via foreach, i will be forced use operator if, and verify each object/array. This is bad way, i think so.

Comment: Your question was "Why i get different results?" to which you got an answer. If your question is "How to parse it?" then formulate it better and update the post.

Comment: Does `foreach($cursor as $model){var_dump($model->user);}` prints that user array or does it also throw an exception?

Comment: Above i update post, what it generate notice, because we not must try get access to object (MongoID).

Comment: Sorry man, I don't understand what you are trying to say. Phalcon handles mongo ids fine according to documentation if that's what you mean…